# Render css js img files in gorilla mux

Tags: html, css, http, go, gorilla

Learning Gorilla Toolkit and golang so please go easy here. Would like to render .css, .js, and .jpeg files in their corresponding folders.

File Structure is:

```
ROOT/
 |--main.go, message.go
 |
 |Templates/
 |   |--index.html,confirmation.html
 |
 |Static/
   |
   |css/
   |--ex1.css, ex2.css
   |   
   |js/
   |--ex1.js, ex2.js
   |
   |Images/ 
   |--ex1.jpeg, ex2.jpeg
```

Package main with gorilla pat and mux as follows:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "github.com/gorilla/pat"
  "html/template"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {

  r := pat.New()
  r.Get("/", http.HandlerFunc(index))
  r.Post("/", http.HandlerFunc(send))
  r.Get("/confirmation", http.HandlerFunc(confirmation))

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080",r)

  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/", Home)
  router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/",http.FileServer(http.Dir(./static/))))
  http.Handle("/", router)
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8443", router)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Getting error:

```
.\main.go:23: syntax error: unexpected .
```

Not sure how to run multiple http servers through func main to start app and render all files nested in static folder.

Comment: `http.Dir` takes a string as an argument. You need to have `http.Dir("./static")`. There's also no space between the assignment operator `:=` and `http.ListenAndServe`, as well as mixed cases for `index` and `Index` handler functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

- Make the parameter to http.Dir a string: `http.Dir("./static/")`.
- Run the first `http.ListenAndServe` in a separate Goroutine using the `go` command.
- Remove the line `http.Handle("/", router)`. This registers the Gorilla Mux router as the handler for `/` in the `http.DefaultServeMux`, which you then don't use at all. So it can be safely removed.

Like so:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/pat"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    r := pat.New()
    r.Get("/", http.HandlerFunc(index))
    // etc...

    log.Println("Listening on :8080...")
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", home)
    router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))

    log.Println("Listening on :8443...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8443", router)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Index page"))
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Home page"))
}
```